# How to update seaborn data when I use django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I use django and create web page. Then I click button seaborn do not update data, only add data.
Scatters are added to the plot as many times as I click the button. However I want reset existing data and show new plot by new data.

Django code:

```
def index(request):
   if request.method == "GET":

      form_index = ForecastField(request.GET)
       if form_index.is_valid():
         adress_f = form_index.cleaned_data['flat_Ad']
         newdf_pl = pd.read_csv(r'newdf.csv')
         newdf_pl = newdf_pl.loc[newdf_pl['Address_N'] == adress_f]

         sns.scatterplot(data=newdf_pl, x='Area', y='Price_G')
         fig = plt.gcf()
         buff = BytesIO()
         fig.savefig(buff, format='png')
         buff.seek(0)
         string = base64.b64encode(buff.read())
         uri_F = urllib.parse.quote(string)

         context = {'Index_f': ForecastField(), 'pngg_F': uri_F}

         html_index = "MyHome/index.html"
         return render(request, html_index, context)
```

HTML code:

```
<div class='container'>
    <img src='data:image/png;base64,{{ pngg_F }}' alt="image"/>
</div>
```

Comment: you should post what your _seaborn button_ does